# When is `struct file*` is created for open file in kernel space?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel

I am learning Linux Kernel mostly reading [LDD3](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). And I am a bit confused. That said (ch3, p.53):

> The `file` structure represents an *open file*. (It is not specific to device drivers; every
>   open file in the system has an associated `struct file` in kernel space.) It is created by
>   the kernel on *open* and is passed to any function that operates on the file, until
>   the last *close*. After all instances of the file are closed, the kernel releases the data
>   structure.

On the other hand, earlier one can read about `open` file operation (ch3, p.51) :

> Though this is always the first operation performed on the device file, the driver
>   is not required to declare a corresponding method. If this entry is NULL , opening
>   the device always succeeds, but your driver isn’t notified.

So if I don't provide this file operation then when the `file` corresponding to my open file is created? For example, I have written a small example which produces a file in the `/proc` filesystem, but has not provided the `open` file operation --- only the `read` operation:

```
static struct file_operations this_proc_ops = 
{
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = this_proc_read
};
```

and I can open it and read it successfully. I imagine that it wouldn't be possible without corresponding `file` in kernel-space, would it? So my question is when the `struct file` is created in this case?

Comment: There is common kernel open processing that occurs before a driver's `open`, if defined, is called. That's why a driver does not need to define open if there is no driver specific operations needed.

Comment: @kaylum, Yes. Suppose that step 3.a answers my question. Thanks.